# Make button transparent in Java AWT

Tags: java, button, awt, transparent

Is it possible to make buttons in AWT transparent? I drew an image and aligned parts of it with buttons.

```
Button start = new Button ();
start.setBounds(98, 333, 326, 51);
start.setBackground(null);
```

Comment: Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know any method to make an awt.button transparent with a single line of code. But maybe a work around would be to place a label and add a click listener to the label ?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I figured was just to use a rectangle then add a mousepressed event.

This solution is if you are trying to get the background image to appear as a design for your button.